# Fetching data from a website using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I would like to know whether I can use python for fetching data from a website by giving some specific inputs.
I know i should write somewhat code, but here I'm starting from scratch and bit confused, Hope you'll understand..

Explanation:

This is our university website:

*http://exam.cusat.ac.in/*

I want to click on the First Link through the program which is Given in the Website as,

*Download/View Result for B.Tech  V Semester  November 2016 - Regular Examination*

Then the next page has an option to enter the registration number, as I know the register number, I can assign it to a variable.
Here I want to get the results of multiple students, that is the main aim of the program.

eg: The results starting from 12153600 to 12153660 should be retrieved one by one from the website.

The last thing is that if i can get then results the can I convert it into PDF? If possible can I convert all of those results into a single PDF File as different pages?

Comment: why do you want the results of sixty different students with 60 consecutive consecutive registration numbers?

Comment: Actually it's for data manipulation...@MaxPower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my observations with the site:

1. The site uses form to display the result of the student
2. Form url is `http://exam.cusat.ac.in/erp5/cusat/CUSAT-RESULT/Result_Declaration/display_sup_result`
3. Form method is POST
4. Data passed to url are `regno,deg_name,semester,year,result_type`

so you need to raise post request to the url with the above mentioned parameters.You can do that in simple python and requests.

```
import requests # to make requests.
import pdfkit # for saving as pdf
url="http://exam.cusat.ac.in/erp5/cusat/CUSAT-RESULT/Result_Declaration/display_sup_result" #form url
pdfs=[]
payload={ "deg_name":"B.Tech", "semester":"5", "month":"November", "year":"2016", "result_type":"Regular" }
option={'quiet': ''}
for i in range(12153600,12153660+1):
    payload.update({"regno":str(i)})
    response=requests.post(url,data=payload)
    pdfkit.from_string(response.content,str(i)+".pdf",options=option) #saves to 12153600.pdf - 12153660.pdf files
    open("result_"+str(i)+".html","w").write(response.content) #This will save results from roll no 12153600 - 12153660 in result_rollno.html files.
```

This creates 60 seperate pdf files.

To save the response as pdf files you can use `pdfkit`
refer [this for installation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit), [this for tutorial](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python-using-pdfkit/). I want you to go through the pdf saving part as hands on. So I'm skipping saving as pdf part. If you find it difficult there are no of packages to save data as pdf in python which you can google. I prefer this because this accepts a list as inputs/files so you can add all the responses to a list and use this to create a single pdf file.

Comment: First of all thanks alot @Mani..That was the thing which I want...But still I've some issues with it.. I used  pdfkit but the desired output was not in the exact form... The output obtained was not properly formatted even there was no css file for the resulting html page...
When I click print to PDF from the result page it's being properly aligned where as while using pdfkit doesn't.. Please help me...

Comment: Could you please see this question... @Mani
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524495/converting-html-file-to-pdf-with-python

Comment: I checked it once again in my pc it is working fine did you install webkit using `apt-get` as mentioned in installation page?

Comment: Actually I'm using mac.. Currently my issue is that the pdf file is not being exactly as I want..
See this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524495/converting-html-file-to-pdf-with-python
In that, What I need is an output PDF file as the first screenshot whereas I'm currently receiving the PDF file as the Second Screenshot.

Comment: I don't have mac to execute and check the code but in my pc it is working fine. Check how to install webkit i think it should be having problem.

Comment: if you don't mind, will you please post a screenshot? @Mani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142302/discussion-between-mani-and-ajay-victor).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) python library.

You'll be able to achieve what you want with that library. Specifically, you would use Selenium's get function to get your website, selenium's click function to click the first link, and so on.

A lot of researchers use that to simulating click events on websites such as Facebook and gathering the resulting data.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout Request Module for getting data from Html.

PFB the links for tutorial purpose:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/requests/master/requests.pdf

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment. You are pointing them in the right direction, but not really answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `requests` library for sending the requests and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html that you receive.

First, you need to inspect the page using your browser's dev tools. If you do that, you will find that each link row is a `form` element -

```
<form id="myForm0121x1" action="..." method="post">
<input name="month" value="..." type="hidden">
<input name="year" value="..." type="hidden">
<input name="sem" value="..." type="hidden">
<input name="reg_type" value="..." type="hidden">
<input name="dn" value="..." type="hidden">
<input name="status1" value="..." type="hidden">
</form>
```

Each link is a `POST` request to the `action` attribute's url value along with the `input` elements. To do this programmatically using `requests` -

```
r = requests.post('url',data={'month':'...','year':'...','sem':'...','reg_type':'...','dn':'...','status1':'...'})
```

If you then check `r.content`, you will have received the source of the [second page](http://exam.cusat.ac.in/erp5/cusat/CUSAT-RESULT/latest_uni_result/rresult1). Repeat the above process again for this page, this time changing the data parameter's keys/values accordingly(use the inspector) and add an extra `'regno':'xyz'`(where xyz = a registration number), and you will receive the final html content for a student's result page. Parse this using `BeautifulSoup` and pick up whatever you need.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is good approach. I also use BeautifulSoup for crawl process